# Why is my TeamCity Admin user no longer an Admin user after I switch over to NTLM authentication?

Tags: teamcity, ntlm, role, manual

Just installed teamcity 6.5.6 after uninstalling 6.5.4 after trying to implement a svn 1.7 plugin that seemed to have buggered up my TC configurations.

Trying to revert back to working times so I did a fresh install of the latest release.

I created my initial admin user with the same credential I have for the admin user on the server machine that is running TC.
Once I change the config to NTLM auth, I login as the same user, and that user no longer has admin privileges. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation states that:

*Please note that each authentication type maintains own list for users. This means that on switching from one authentication to another you start with no users (and no administrator) and will be prompted for administrator account on first TeamCity start after the authentication change. This also means that all the existing users will need to create their accounts and re-enter their settings anew.*

So when you switched to NLTM authentication you will have be prompted to specify the admin user again.

http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD65/Configuring+Authentication+Settings

Comment: i thought so too. i wonder why i wasn't prompted then? is it because i changed auth while i was logged in as my intended admin? it never prompted me.

Comment: it also states: If you are not prompted for administrator account on switching to a new scheme, this means that there are users in the scheme already.

Comment: it also states Also, TeamCity plugins can provide additional authentication schemes. Please restart the server after editing the file. So there you have it.